# Plaintext Size Limit for ECIES with AES-128 CBC mode

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, ecies

Using the ECIES (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme), is there a limit size of plaintext? (what is the maximum allowed number of bytes to be encrypted with ECIES).

Comment: ECIES : Diffie-Hellman key exchange, coupled with a symmetric encryption scheme, and a MAC. You are free to choose the symmetric encryption scheme. So which one do you want to use.

Comment: The symmetric encryption used by ECIES is the AES with CBC (Cipher.getInstance(”ECIESwithAES-CBC”, new BouncyCastleProvider());).
The other parameters of ECIES, the MAC key size is 128 bits, and the block cipher key size is 128 bits (IESParameterSpec param = new IESParameterSpec(x, y,128, 128, new byte[16]);).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using CBC mode in ECIES. In the CBC mode the $i$-th ciphertext is calculated as

$$c_i = E_k(m_i \oplus c_{i-1})$$

where the $c_0=IV$

Now, there is a problem with CBC mode that is if the adversary can see that $c_i = c_j$ for some $i,j$ with $i \neq j$ then they can calculate:

$$m_i \oplus c_{i-1} = m_j \oplus c_{j-1}$$

and by x-oring both sides they can learn

$$m_i \oplus m_j = c_{i-1} \oplus c_{j-1}.$$

This is ciphertext collision and the probability is given by the birthday bound, $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{2^n})$, where the $n$ is the block size. So it is not advisable to have more than $2^{64}$ blocks. But in practice, you may reduce this into lower sizes to reduce the change of this attack from 50% to your target security level.